# $4\times4\times4$ Rubiks cube Top Layer Issue

Tags: rubiks-cube, algorithm, twisty-puzzles, mechanical-puzzles, solvability

[image]

The only way i am able to solve is to jumble the whole cube again. If you know the way to solve pls give images or algorithm.

Comment: If you truly want to understand the cube and other permutation puzzles, you need to learn commutators, as explained [in this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096592/21820). Then it is obvious that this is a double pair swap, which can be easily done using 2 commutators. Of course there are shorter solutions, but they are ad-hoc and require memorization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a 4x4 Parity.

The algorithm to solve is,

> $(2R)^2U^2(2R)^2u^2(2R)^2(2U)^2$

Where $2R$ is the second layer from right, $U$ is the top layer, $u$ is top two layers combined, $2U$ means second layer from top and the superscript implies you have to turn twice.

First hold the cube in this position.

[image]

## STEP 1: $(2R)^2$

[image]

## STEP 2:  $U^2$

[image]

## STEP 3: $(2R)^2$

[image]

## STEP 4: $u^2$

[image]

## STEP 5: $(2R)^2$

[image]

## STEP 6: $(2U)^2$

[image]

Comment: Beautiful. can you share link for more of these combos

Comment: You can visit https://www.cubeskills.com/ where you can  learn video tutorials of Feliks Zemdegs and you can visit https://www.grubiks.com/ for simulating and solving different cubes.

Comment: thx man.  you rock

Comment: You're welcome!